# c++ conversion string- unsigned char

Tags: c++

I have a string value:
`std::string bl="0x"+"a0";` //where a0 is a heva number. I did add 0x because i want my      vector

```
std::vector<unsigned char>vect;
```

`vect.push_back(bl.begin(), bl.end());` //error  is not working.

Need help. What to do?
I am working in ubuntu c++ code.

Comment: `std::vectorvect` is not valid C++ code.  Please specific `std::vector<T>` for some type `T`.  Then, what values of type `T` do you expect the string bl to be converted into?

Comment: i've edited my post: it's std::vector<unsigned char> vect; And the string bl is a simple string containg a hex value:)

Comment: The letter 'o' is not a valid hex digit.

Comment: it was 0. Sorry for mistake:). So what is the result? how should i write?

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3825553/convert-hex-string-to-hex-value

Comment: OK. Thx!! Can you please tell me how to define an array char x with a dynamic length? And also..why does x.size() not working?

Comment: ok..so..the legth is sizeof(). How do define a dynamic lenght for my array?

Comment: @eliza: For an array with dynamic length, it's best to use a vector. That's what it's for.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not 100% sure on what you want, because of the contents of your string `bl`.

Taking you literally:

```
std::string bl = "0xA0";
// ^ this is what you meant to write ("0x"+"A0" is actually adding pointers)

std::vector<unsigned char> vect;
vect.insert(vect.begin(), bl.begin(), bl.end());
// ^ you use ranges with .insert not push_back
```

Or you can use the constructor:

```
std::string bl = "0xA0";
std::vector<unsigned char> vect(bl.begin(), bl.end());
// ^ you use ranges with the constructor too
```

In both these cases, the vector contains the characters '0', 'x', 'A' and '0'.

Alternatively, you might have meant for the string to contain the single character whose ASCII value is (in hex) `0xA0`. If so, `"0x"+"a0"` is very wrong.

```
std::string bl = "\xA0";
std::vector<unsigned char> vect(bl.begin(), bl.end());
```

The vector contains one character, whose ASCII value is `0xA0`.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Disclaimer: I haven't actually tested this and it's *possible* that you'll need a `std::vector<char>`.

Answer (score 1):

Do not use push_back(...), it classically can not push an interval, it pushs the one item. You can use assign(begin, end) or insert(iter_position, vect_begin, vect_end).

For example:

```
vect.assign(bl.begin(), bl.end());
vect.insert(vect.begin(), bl.begin(), bl.end());
vect.push_back(bl[0]); // '0'
vect.push_back(bl[1]); // 'x'
vect.push_back(bl[2]); // 'a'
vect.push_back(bl[3]); // '0'
```

Answer (score 0):

give type to vector. 
std::vector vec;
to
std::vector< string> vec or whatever you need. and vector push_back signature is  void push_back(const T&). It does not take two arguments.

Comment: refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2206050/how-to-convert-a-string-to-unsigned-char-in-visual-c if you want to convert string to unsigned char.

Comment: No, `std::vector<string>` is not what he means.

Comment: @std258367: You can't convert a string to an unsigned char. Perhaps you meant unsigned char _array_ (as did the author of that question that you linked us to).

Comment: @Tomalak Yes i meant unsigned char aaray

Answer (score -1):

the reason is simple, you are trying to insert an invalid element into your container.

std::string has no implicit conversion to change its data into vector of unsigned char.

Comment: What? I don't see anywhere where he attempted an implicit conversion of a string to a vector.