# C++ Text File Reading

Tags: c++, file-io, formatting

So I need a little help, I've currently got a text file with following data in it:

```
myfile.txt
-----------
b801000000
```

What I want to do is read that b801 etc.. data as bits so I could get values for

```
0xb8 0x01 0x00 0x00 0x00.
```

Current I'm reading that line into a unsigned string using the following typedef.

```
typedef std::basic_string <unsigned char> ustring;
ustring blah = reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char*>(buffer[1].c_str());
```

Where I keep falling down is trying to now get each char {'b', '8' etc...} to really be { '0xb8', '0x01' etc...}

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: It looks like you want to read two bytes in at a time and then interpret as a hex code. An `unsigned char` is still just one byte.

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3825553/convert-hex-string-to-hex-value

Answer (score 1):

I see two ways:

1. Open the file as `std::ios::binary` and use `std::ifstream::operator>>` to extract hexadecimal double bytes after using the flag `std::ios_base::hex` and extracting to a type that is two bytes large (like `stdint.h`'s (C++0x/C99) uint16_t or equivalent). See @neuro's comment to your question for an example using `std::stringstream`s. `std::ifstream` would work nearly identically.
2. Access the stream iterators directly and perform the conversion manually. Harder and more error-prone, not necessarily faster either, but still quite possible.

Answer (score 0):

[strtol](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/strtol.html) does string (needs a nullterminated C string) to int with a specified base

Answer (score 0):

Kind of a dirty way to do it:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
  int num;
  char* value = "b801000000";

  while (*value) {
    sscanf (value, "%2x", &num);
    printf ("New number: %d\n", num);
    value += 2;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Running this, I get:

```
New number: 184
New number: 1
New number: 0
New number: 0
New number: 0
```